# How to hide all other rows in a table

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a table with 3 columns, including Country. I have 3 buttons each representing a country. When I click on a button, say 'Brazil', it highlights all the rows with Brazil in it. But, I want it to hide all the other rows that do not contain Brazil. Same when I click on any other country.

```
<table id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>league</th>
                <th>level</th>
                <th>country</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#Brazil").click(function() {
            $("table tr td:nth-child(3):contains('Brazil')").parent().addClass("brazil");
          });

<style>
      
      .brazil {
        background-color: yellow;
        }
      .argentina {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .bolivia {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      .peru {
        background-color: green;
      }
etc.

</style>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `:not(:contains())` to hide the remaining rows.

Also, we can define a single `onClick` function that will work for all countries if we use `data-attributes` to toggle the class names.

When the user selects a button, we store the `data-attribute` in a variable and then use the variable to check if the td contains the text, if yes, we add the class name to the element.

Then we add another class name to the remaining elements which will hide all the other elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".filter-btn").click(function() {
    let $country = $(this).data('country');
    $("table tr td:nth-child(3):contains('" + $country + "')").parent().removeClass().addClass($country.toLowerCase());
    $("table tr td:nth-child(3):not(:contains(" + $country + "))").parent().addClass('v-hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.brazil {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.argentina {
  background-color: red;
}

.bolivia {
  background-color: blue;
}

.peru {
  background-color: green;
}

.v-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="filter-btn" data-country="Brazil">
  Brazil
</button>

<button class="filter-btn" data-country="Peru">
  Peru
</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Brazil</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Argentina</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Bolivia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>Peru</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Brazil</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Argentina</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It never occured to me to store the data attribute in a variable